# Masking in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to understand masks in actionscript..Everything seems to make sense to me but one part of the code

```
function mouseM(event:MouseEvent):void {
if (mouseclick == 1) {
mask_mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
mask_mc.graphics.drawEllipse(mouseX, mouseY, 70, 60);
mask_mc.graphics.endFill();
}
}
```

I am not sure how to exactly ask this question but here it goes. why does the mask have "begin fill" with a black color? wouldn't that paint the the image in black (I know it doesn't, it just reveals it)? what is the exact function of beginfill (besides revealing the image lool)? like how does it exactly work? sorry if it sounds ridiculously off.. but that part of the code was really screwing me up in understanding masks

Comment: I was going to give this as a formal answer, but perhaps someone can do better. You've already hit the nail on the head. You use the graphics API to "paint" on the mask. The parts that you paint on will reveal the underlying object being masked. It's just how it works. I've never seen a formal explanation of it. I felt the same way as you at first, but eventually you will feel comfortable with the concept. Note that it doesn't matter what color you use. It's just the presence of those graphics on the mask that reveal the underlying object.

Comment: Heh to be honest that was the answer I was looking for thx for clearing it up...Coming from a photoshop and Illustrator background it just seems too alien to me..but I guess I will get used to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is drawing a shape to be used as a mask. In this case, a circle.

It doesn't matter what colour it is as Flash is only interested in the shape of the mask, not the colour.

Once the circle is drawn, Flash checks what part of the circle overlap the object you're masking so that every pixel the circle is **not** covering will be invisible. I guess it should really be called an anti-mask as the circle dictates which parts of your image **wont** be masked but it's just become the general convention to call the circle *(or whatever shape you use)* the mask.

Again, you're just creating a shape to be used as a mask. Setting the colour is just so the object can essentially exist.. because you can't exactly have a transparent circle.

Feel free to change the colour to anything and you'll see it makes no difference, the shape is all that matters.